# Oracle error when creating table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Driver(
Driver_ID number(10) Primary key,
DriverFname varchar(15),
DriverLname varchar(15),
Train_ID number(10) Foreign key References
Train(Train_ID)
);
```

I get this error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis when I try to run it

Comment: You should really take the time and learn how to read the syntax diagrams in the Oracle manual. This is all explained in great detail there: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#CJAEDFIB

Answer (score 1):

take out the `Foreign key` - you don't need that. just `Train_ID number(10) References Train(Train_ID)`

so run this:

```
CREATE TABLE Driver(
Driver_ID number(10) Primary key,
DriverFname varchar(15),
DriverLname varchar(15),
Train_ID number(10)  References
Train(Train_ID)
);
```

Comment: finally man i love you and this still makes Train_ID a foreign key right? and how come I don't need the foreign key syntax?

Comment: yeah, still creates a foreign key constraint. this is basically shorthand - you get a constraint created with a randomly assigned name. if you want to go the whole hog you can do this: `CONSTRAINT driver_train_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (Train_ID)
REFERENCES Train(Train_Id)` - works the same way. the driver_train_id_fk is just an example name for the constraint - you can call it whatever you want if you actually want to name it.

Comment: If I want to insert a driver  ID=333 FName=Bob Lname=Builder Train_ID=222 how would I do it. Just asking so I don't need to ask if it doesnt work

Comment: `insert into driver (driver_id, driverfname, driverlname, train_id) values (333, 'Bob','Builder',222)`- this will fail though if you don't have a row in the 'Train' table with a 'Train_ID' of 222.

Comment: in my train table i have train_ID and train_capacity so I do                insert into train(train_ID, train_capacity) values (222,35)?

Comment: yep. because of the foreign key you need the train before you can create the driver.

Comment: k one last question. 1)Using a query list all drivers in your driver table. 2) using a query list all trains that are driven by the first driver. 3) using a query find how many trains you have in your train table

Comment: I'm not making you do my homework just need it since I have more tables Driver,Train,Schedule,Route,Stop,Route_Stop.

Comment: @SKTT1Faker Please don't ask additional questions in the comments. Post a new question instead. And please accept Trent's answer if it solved your problem.